# iPhone Login Notifications

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, restful-authentication

Had a question related to best practices in iPhone login authentication using asynchronous NSURLConnection.

Since the same delegate is used for logging into a server, how do folks differentiate notifications coming back for an authentication request, versus when you recieve data for subsequent data requests?

Thanks,

Sj

Answer (score 1):

If by authentication, you mean HTTP authentication, then that is not handed back to you as data. It comes back in `-connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`. If you're talking about a higher-level protocol that manages authentication above the HTTP layer, then it's your job to keep track of the current state of your connection.

See [Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-160393) for full details on HTTP Auth.

Comment: So I've got auth working, what I don't understand is how to differentiate didRetrieveData for different requests. What I'm wondering about is how do you differentiate a didRetrieveData for an auth request, versus the same for a request of another nature (fetching json for ex).

Thanks Rob.

Comment: If we're talking HTTP Auth, then you shouldn't get didReceiveData an an HTTP auth challenge. What kind of auth request are your referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern to use would be to create a different class for each type of request you have and make it manage the lifetime its own `NSURLConnection`. It can then send events back to its delegate.

The other method would be to remember all the `NSURLConnection`s you've created and compare them against the first parameter of the delegate callbacks.